# Spring-Boot @TestPropertySource not loading the external properties file when used with @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I am new to Spring Boot, I am having trouble in loading properties file using @TestPropertySource annotation along with @SpringBootTest , Here is my code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test_application.properties")
@Sql(value = {"/user_test_script.sql"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class UserServiceImpleIntegrationTest {


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @Test
    public void testGetAllGuestUsers() throws IOException {
        List<User> users =userService.getAllGuestUsers(0, 10);

        assertThat(users).isNotNull();
        assertThat(users).isNotEmpty();
        assertThat(users).are(new Condition<User>() {
               public boolean matches(User user) {
                     return user.getFirstName().contains("Guest");  }
                 });
    }
}
```

Here is my test_application.properties file content

```
# Connection url for the database "test"
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root


# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1


#LOGGING
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE 
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG

spring.profiles.active=junit

#TransactionManagement
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE
```

My classpath:test_application.properties is located in src/test/resources location.

When I used the same @TestPropertySource annotation with @DataJpaTest ,properties files are loading as excepted.Here is my code for the same

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
@Sql(value = {"/item_test_script.sql" ,"/image_test_script.sql"})
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:test_application.properties") 
public class ItemRepoTest {


    @Autowired
    ItemRepo itemRepo;

    @Test
    public void testGetAllImagesByItemId() {
        List<Image> images= itemRepo.getAllImagesByItemId(1l);
        assertThat(images).isNotEmpty();
        assertThat(images).size().isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);

    }

}
```

The very strange thing is If I use properties attribute as

> @TestPropertySource(properties=
>   {"spring.datasource.username=root","spring.datasource.password=root"})

instead of location attribute then these values are taken to load the database.what I am missing here , Or what configuration is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having @Configuration in one of my Test configuration Class instead of @TestConfiguration Annotation , So the application.properties file  is loaded and replacing the test_application.properties file

Answer (score 4):

Try removing classpath from the annotation, should look like this.
`@TestPropertySource("test_application.properties")`

`@TestPropertySource` is usually used in conjunction with  `@ContextConfiguration`